# Windows batch: run a process in background and wait for it

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-shell

I need to start 2 background processes from my batch job and then wait for them. Unix shell analogue is:

```
myprocess1 -flags1 &
pid1=$!

myprocess2 -flags2 &
pid2=$!

wait ${pid1}
wait ${pid2}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's an idea of installing `bash` for Windows or something like that (I'm sure there were a native, non-cygwin port of `zsh`, at least). I'm tempted to recommend the same thing for many batch-file questions, but for this one it could be really a good answer.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Thank you. I was thinking about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve it, using a start wrapper.

The wrapper starts a process with `start /wait` and after the process is finished it deletes a file for signaling.

The first process you start through the wrapper, the second you can start with `start /wait`.
Then you only need to wait for the file.

```
Echo > waiting.tmp 
Start cmd /c wrapper.bat myprocess1 -flags1
start /wait myprocess2 -flags2

:loop
if exist waiting.tmp goto :loop
```

content of wrapper.bat

```
start /wait %*
del waiting.tmp
```

Comment: +1 - you could reverse the logic and start with a "waiting.tmp" and signal completion by deleting the file. One less line of code in the master script :-)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I changed it to your clever suggestion

Comment: If using my suggestion, then wrapper.bat must delete the .tmp file, and I think the .tmp file should be renamed to "waiting.tmp". Also, I just noticed that the wrapper should not use the `/wait` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `START` command:

```
START /WAIT myprocess1 -flags1
```

The only issue is that AFAIK you cannot let processes run in parallel and wait for both of them -- they have to run sequentially.

You might be able to do concurrency by starting the two processes without `START /WAIT`, then periodically parse the output of the `TASKLIST` command to see if they are still running. This is going to be more complicated and of course it's a busy wait, but in theory would allow the processes to run concurrently.

Comment: I really need to run the processes in parallel. Also I'd like to avoid   parsing if it is possible.