# run python scripts in batch and wait for return from their executions

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

How do I write a batch script in windows that starts 2 python scripts and waits for both of them to return? and also terminates both of them if I terminate the batch script?

Already asked this and got no answers...Also looked for solutions here, but the ones listed do not wait for a return from execution of the python scripts.

EDIT: yes terminate it using ctrl+C

Comment: For starting and waiting, you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747963/windows-batch-run-a-process-in-background-and-wait-for-it).  Killing them off, however, I am not sure in batch.

Comment: How would you terminate the batch ? Ctrl-C ?

Comment: Do you want that the python scripts run one after the other, or in parallel, and do you need to do anything with their return code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure that the other scripts wait for your proccess to be complete, call it using `start /wait` - this calls another batch or command line script:

```
start /wait batchforpython.bat
```

so`batchforpython.bat` would contain

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:\Where\your\python\file\is.py
```

which is how you can call your python program from a batch script.

Finally, in Python, you can [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429250/determining-running-programs-in-python) to check if a program is running (for you, that would be `cmd` or `command.com`) and if it is not there then the batch script has been terminated, so you can use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) to exit Python.